# Spring Kafka multiple serializers and consumer/container factories

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my Spring Boot application, I configured Kafka with the following Sender/Receiver:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaSenderConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, ImportDecisionMessage> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, ImportDecisionMessage> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}

@Configuration
public class KafkaReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String consumerGroupId;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, ImportDecisionMessage> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(ImportDecisionMessage.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ImportDecisionMessage> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ImportDecisionMessage> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

}
```

Based on this configuration right now I'm only able to work with my POJO - `ImportDecisionMessage` and use `JsonDeserializer` serializer for send/receive messages.

I also have to have possibility to send another POJOs as messages, for example, `Product`, `Car`, `Category`

Also, I'd like to use another `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesSerializer` for `Car` also.

How to properly extend my configuration in order to support these types and serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s impossible because:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

Are exactly Apache Kafka properties. And that one supports only simple plain deserialization strategy. You should consider you custom logic downstream already from the raw `byte[]` returned from the Kafka Consumer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it mean that the only one pair of Serializer/Deserializer can be configured with Kafka for all application(for example String, or JSON, or Bytes.. etc)?
Could you please also show how to extend my configuration in order to support another messages types, like Product, Car, Category(not only ImportDecisionMessage)?

Comment: No, that’s per consumer. You can configure several consumers with different options. But indeed they all should look into the different partitions at least. OTOH the ContainerFactory can be be configured with the `MessageConverter` also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes